# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:/... on line 10

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 

$name=$_POST['name'];
$telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("comments",$conn);

$sql= "INSERT INTO inside VALUES{($_POST['name']),($_POST['telephone']),($_POST['comment'])}";

if(mysql_query($sql,$conn))
{
echo 'record added';
}
else
{
echo 'error';
}
?>
```

I don't know what is the error in line 10, line 10 is:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO inside VALUES{($_POST['name']),($_POST['telephone']),($_POST['comment'])}";
```

My database name is comments and table name is inside, and also sometimes when I finished this I got the result as 'error' I think it comes from the line 18. can you please tell me how to solve this, I'am fed of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your query. You need to have the curley brackets around every `$_POST` in your query, and your query should be `... VALUE (....)`

change -

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO inside VALUES{($_POST['name']),($_POST['telephone']),($_POST['comment'])}";
```

to

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO inside VALUES ( {$_POST['name']}, {$_POST['telephone']},{$_POST['comment']})";
```

see
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html
and
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

---

also, you should not be inserting user data directly into your database. take a look at
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)